# problemas al guardar hora

Tags: php

saludos amigos tengo un problema cuando se guarda la hora resulta que si son las 12:45pm el me guarda la hora 12:15:47PM el formato que uso es el siguiente:

```
 <?php
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');
 ?>
 <input type='hidden' name='hora' value='<?php echo date('h:i:sA'); ?>' />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tu zona horaria donde te encuentras tu es America/Caracas ?

Comment: Si exacto ¿Y tu donde estas?

Comment: estoy en Venezuela.

Answer (score 1):

Al momento de responder, en Caracas deben ser las `02:38PM`

Mira los ejemplos de código. Si no quieres los segundos, tan sólo tienes que omitir la `s`.

Si no te funciona, el problema está en otra parte, no en el código.

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/BIP50912)

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas'); 
echo date('H:i:sA');
echo "\n";
echo date('h:i:sA');
echo "\n";
echo date('H:iA');
echo "\n";
echo date('h:iA');

?>
```

#### `Resultado`

```
14:38:06PM
02:38:06PM
14:38PM
02:38PM
```

---

#### EDIT

También puedes usar la clase [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php) de PHP, la cual es más flexible y potente que la función `date`.

Creas un objeto `$date` mediante `new` y le aplicas la zona. Luego haces `echo` del objeto con el formato que quieras.

Ejemplo:

**Código:**

```
$date = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/Caracas'));
echo $date->format('H:i:sA');
```

**Resultado:**

```
14:54:35PM
```

Comment: creo que hay un problema

Comment: fijate en la imagen que voy a poner

Comment: @yoclens ¿Y si pruebas con `DateTime` como muestro en el EDIT de la respuesta, comentado o quitando en el código todo lo que huela a `date_default_timezone_set`.?

Comment: ya lo hice de verdad no se que pasa

Comment: ¿No será la zona horaria de tu equipo que está mal @yoclens  o algún bug de tu PHP? ¿Qué versión de PHP tienes? **¿Qué muestra: `echo date_default_timezone_get();`**?

Comment: America/Caracas

Comment: Que extraño. ¿Seguro que está bien configurado en php.ini? ¿Chequeaste la zona horaria del sistema en la configuración? ¿Probaste a reiniciar el equipo?

Comment: [Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone=America/Caracas

Comment: @yoclens faltan las comillas: `date.timezone="America/Caracas"` y revisa que no esté seteado de otra forma en otra parte de php.ini

Comment: igual ya lo correji pero sigue igual pero cuando introduzco ese código en el servidor en web me funciona bien me imagino que web ser problemas con mi server local

Comment: Es extraño. Te he comentado todas las posibles causas que imagino. También puede ser que tu servidor esté apuntando a otro `php.ini` diferente del que estés modifcando, o que la zona horaria se setee en otra parte del `php.ini`, más abajo, o en otra parte (apache u otro) o un problema en la configuración del equipo (Windows, Mac, Linux).  No se me ocurre otra cosa.

Comment: donde pudeo ver eso si el server esta apuntando a otro php.ini

Comment: Puedes usar [`phpinfo();`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.phpinfo.php)  @yoclens

Answer (score 0):

Prueba Sumando o restando minutos faltantes

```
<?php
$time = time();
?>
<input type='hidden' name='hora' value='<?php  echo date("d-m-Y (H:i:s)", $time +1800); ?>' />
```

Comment: No creo que la solución se restar o sumar, si se puede obtener directamente la hora exacta.

Comment: y mi archivo php.ini esta bien, el formato es
date.timezone=America/Caracas