# Establecer zona horaria

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Quiero establecer zona horaria para mi proyecto. Este es mi código:

**Establezco el formato de esta manera:**

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Caracas");
setlocale(LC_ALL,"es_ES@euro","es_ES","esp");
```

**Y lo imprimo de esta manera:**

```
    $time = date('H:i:s a', time());
    echo $time;
```

Me imprime la hora pero con **30 min** de retraso.

Comment: Creo que puede ser por el servidor donde está alojada la web. A mi me ha pasado varias veces y por más que le digo el default timezone, al final me toca hacer el cálculo a mi y ponerle de más o de menos.

Lo que me ha funcionado a mi a veces es modificar (siempre que tenga la opción claro) el php.ini o el httpd.config de apache

Comment: Puedes trabajar con objetos `DateTime`, es más fácil y más flexible. Por ejemplo: `$timeZone=new DateTimeZone('America/Caracas');
$date = new DateTime("now",  $timeZone);
echo $date->format('H:i:s a');`, te arrojará la hora: `11:09:57 am` ¿no es esa la hora en Caracas?

Comment: Y a ver si no hay algún problema con la hora en Caracas, pues [no es la primera vez que ocurre algo parecido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/86806/29967). Al final nunca supe si el problema se resolvió. Probando el código en rextester funciona bien. Empiezo a sospechar que puede ser un problema relativo a los servidores en Caracas.

Comment: En efecto, [en abril 2016 Maduro adelantó 30 minutos a la hora de Venezuela](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/venezuela-change-timezone.html), y al parecer muchos servidores no han registrado aún ese cambio. [Ver aquí](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/wrong-time-zone-values-for-caracas-venezuela-829032043.html) el problema planteado en un foro de soporte,  [ver también en el foro de Google](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/gUhIyoiflu8). Creo que eso explica lo que está ocurriendo y lo que ocurría en la pregunta planteada en el enlace de mi comentario anterior.